# How to define a repeat function with macros

Tags: clojure, macros

I want to write a function (rep-n-times n & args), which should work like:

```
user=>(rep-n-times 3 (print "hello!") (print "bye"))
hello! bye hello! bye hello! bye nil
```

My code is

```
(defmacro ntimes [n & body]
      `(take ~n (repeat ~@body)))
```

Testing:

```
#'user/rep-n-times
user=> (rep-n-ntimes 5 (print "hah"))
hah(nil nil nil nil nil)
user=> (macroexpand '(rep-n-ntimes 4 (print "hello")))
(clojure.core/take 4 (clojure.core/repeat (print "hello")))
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3):

In this case where you are doing things for side effects, you should use `doseq` or `dotimes` instead:

```
(dotimes [i 3]
  (print "hello! bye "))
```

There is no need to define rep-n-times. If you need the results of a function with side-effects, use `repeatedly`. Note also that `repeatedly` and `repeat` optionally takes the number of repetitions as an argument.

```
(repeatedly 3 (fn [] (print "hello! bye ") (rand-int 10)))
```

However as to the problem with your definition of `rep-n-times`, calling `repeat` takes a single argument, which is the evaluated result of `(print "hello")` which is nil. So you are asking for 4 nils, and getting 4 nils. The print occurs one time, when the argument is evaluated to nil. Also it produces a lazy sequence, which happens to be evaluated at the REPL, but that is just because it is being printed. You should avoid having side effects (such as printing) inside a lazy sequence, because they will not be evaluated unless you explicitly realize the sequence.

Note that `dotimes` can take many forms:

```
(dotimes [i 3] (print "h1") (print "h2") (print "h3"))
```

And that dotimes is a macro defined [here](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/010864f8ed828f8d261807b7345f1a539c5b20df/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L3204)

You can write your own version by using that code as a starting point:

```
(defmacro rep-n-times [n & body]
  `(loop [i# ~n]
     (when (pos? i#)
       ~@body
       (recur (dec i#)))))
```

Comment: Hi Timothy! I totally agree with you! However, I am sorry that I did not make my question clear. I was asked to write a function which must be defined with macros, and I am not going to repeat the same string. As my question above, the function takes one or two or more arguments.Like, (rep-n-times 5 (print "hello") (print "good") (print "night")....).

Comment: Hi Xiufen, OK, I added an example of how to implement it as a macro to the answer.

Comment: Hi Timothy! I really appreciate that.  I looked up a lot materials about auto-gensym and gensym, but I still have no idea what those exactly do. What does it mean "use gensym to get a unique identifier"? Thanks

Comment: Well the problem with using a symbol inside a macro is that it might conflict with another symbol. For example if we just used `i` as our symbol instead of `i#` then the meaning of `i` would be changed. So if we wrote `(let [i 1] (rep-n-times 3 (println i)))` we would get surprised by the result. `i#` makes a randomized symbol name, so that it will be bound inside the expanded code created by the macro with a unique name. That's all it really means.